# How to make a python autotyper work in an app in the background (If it is possible)

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I just wanted to see if I could create a python script that could type in the background. I have a code that auto types a phrase and has a 60 second interval, in that time, you place the cursor where you want the script to type. I also have included the script to press enter after. I was wondering, if this could also work on another app open in the background. For example, it would type in another app, while the user could use their device for other purposes. I'm pretty sure that this is not possible but I just wanted to check. I am doing this for a challenge set by my peers.

The code I have so far is shown below

```
import time
from keyboard import press

while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    pyautogui.typewrite("""Hello World!""")
    press('enter')
```

In addition if the device were to have its display turned off, would the program still run?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 Education Edition

Comment: @Daweo I have a HP laptop if that helps.